# AngularJS switch css theme on user selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the themes from bootswatch and I'm trying to allow the user to switch the theme. When the theme is switched all the bootstap css temporarily goes away until the new theme is loaded. How can I prevent the change until the css is loaded or switch back to the default theme until the new one is loaded?

index.ejs (in the head)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/external/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_yeti.min.css"
      ng-if="myTheme == ''">
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="/external/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_{{myTheme}}.min.css"
      ng-if="myTheme != ''">
```

Selection

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="theme"
        name="theme"
        ng-model="theme"
        ng-change="newTheme()">
  <option value="" disabled>Select Theme</option>
  <option ng-repeat="(key, val) in availableThemes" value="{{val}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

controller on index

```
$scope.myTheme = '';
$rootScope.$watch('myTheme', function(value) {
  if (value != undefined) {
    $scope.myTheme = value;
  }
});
```

controller for selection

```
$scope.availableThemes = {
  Cerulean: 'cerulean',
  Cosmo:    'cosmo',
  Yeti:     'yeti'
};
$scope.newTheme = function() {
  console.log($scope.theme);
  if ($scope.theme != undefined) {
    $rootScope.myTheme = $scope.theme;
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Try using one of those async loading libraries like requirejs or dominoes etc and change the myTheme variable inside their callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is not a problem of AngularJS. I think your approach should be different.

As I know, theme functionality is usually implemented like below.

1. Create a single CSS file for each theme (cerulean, cosmo, yeti). You should edit CSS files not to conflict each other. (put .cerulean, .cosmo, .yeti in front of all CSS selectors. If you use sass or less, it will be much easier.)
2. Load all CSS files from the HTML head.

   > ```
   > <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_cerulean.min.css">
   > <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_cosmo.min.css">
   > <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_yeti.min.css">
   > ```
3. If a user select a theme, change a class of body or root element to a corresponding theme name.

   > ```
   > <body class="cerulean">
   > <body class="cosmo">
   > <body class="yeti">
   > ```

Comment: I found that I could also add the async tag to the second stylesheet link and while it loads, the previous stylesheet would be used. However your solution is better. If the second stylesheet is missing anything that the first one has then you'll be getting a mixture of the css files

Comment: I do not like this idea. I have the same case and i whant to use 10 themes and i am not sure that everyone will use it at all. Tell me why my app have to load 1 extra megabyte? I think there have to the way.

Comment: this approach made my project so much simpler. Thank you! I was overlooking for something so obvious.

Answer (score 10):

I find it better to keep it simple, and there's no need to pre-load all the themes like other have suggested.

Stick to a single  tag with ng-href:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="/external/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_{{myTheme}}.min.css">
```

And initialize myVar in your scope to "yeti" in the index controller:

```
$scope.myTheme = 'yeti';
$rootScope.$watch('myTheme', function(value) {
  if (value != undefined) {
    $scope.myTheme = value;
  }
});
```

The rest stays the same.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the temporary lack of theme while the page is loading?

Comment: @Josep Sayol better answer in terms of angular!

Answer (score 4):

try this approach it will work..

```
<link href="css/style1.css" ng-if="load">
<link href="css/style2.css" ng-if="!load">

<body>
<input type="button" ng-click="changeTheme()" value="Change Theme"/>
</body>
<script>
$scope.load=true;
$scope.changeTheme=function(){
$scope.load=!$scope.load;
}
<script>
```

Comment: good work bro! quick, simple, efficient, I'll rename and add a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you include all your themes at first load, them all of them have to be loaded by the browser. And it is not even clear if user will ever switch themes. So why should you load all of them. So here are few options.

**1. Ng-if**

Try to ad `ng-if` to `link`

```
<link ng-if="theme" ng-href="{{theme}}">
```

I am not sure if it will work but i have read somewhere that it worked for some people

**2. Visibility**

I am typing from ipad so ill be short.

Create css file with something like this

```
Body .container {display:none}
Body .loader {display:block}
```

Put all you content into container class div. create sibling div class loader and place loader animation there.

Load/link this file first in the head. Then link your theme in every theme add cancelation of those rules.

```
Body .container {display:block}
Body .loader {display:none}
```

So on the moment of css reload you will have a loader animation.