# using different themes for each user type in a single angularJs app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I m developing angularJs single page app. Currently my app have four kind of user (guest, student, Instructor, admin). I want to shown different dashboard for each user role mean i want to show different theme for each user. How can i do this in a single page app.
I have seen this" [AngularJS switch css theme on user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568801/angularjs-switch-css-theme-on-user-selection)
 " but i couldn't able to understand the idea.

Comment: please add code what you have tried till now. the link you provided explains about switching css based on user which is simple using `css`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single css file having 4 parent classes

> .guest, .student, .instructor and .admin

Now in your app use `ng-class` in your parent div, see syntax below

```
<div ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}">
Hello World!
</div>
```

Let say `userType` holds the value of the type of user logged in, then

```
<body ng-class="{guest : userType===guest, student : userType===student, instructor : userType===instructor, admin : userType===admin}">
Hello World!
</body>
```

OR you can use the if else conditions as

```
<div ng-class=" ... ? 'class-1' : ( ... ? 'class-2' : 'class-3')">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to develop one css file that will be responsible for layout and basic styling, like:

```
.component1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Then in separate css files develop the styles for specific user, like so:

```
.theme1 .component1 {
  color: red;
  background: gray;
}
```

Another theme like so:

```
.theme2 .component2 {
  color: green;
  background: blue;
}
```

And the last step is to add on  tag ng-class="{'theme1': userType== 'instructor', 'theme2': userType =='admin'...}".

That's basically what the question you mentioned explains.